# How do I count instances based on the header?

Tags: excel

I have a problem where I am counting the number of "Yes" in a table that is formatted in this manner:

| A | B | A | B | How many Yes in a column that is an A? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes | No | No | should be 1 |
| No | Yes | No | Yes | should be 0 |

I imagine it is a Countif but how do I make sure the header must be an A? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUMPRODUCT()` function like-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$D$1="A")*(A2:D2="Yes"))
```

[image]